# Error on writing files in php

Tags: php

i have this php code:

```
<?php
echo ("Setting up data..."); 
$today = date("YmdHi");
$wtoday = $today
$im = $_GET["im"];
$fim = "tips/$today/im.txt";
$fwtoday = "tips/$today/today.txt";
?>
<?php
$fp = fopen ($fwtoday, "w"); # w = write to the file only, create file if it does not exist, discard existing contents 
if ($fp) { 
    fwrite ($fp, $wtoday); 
    fclose ($fp); 
    echo ("Today written"); 
} 
else { 
    echo ("Today was not written"); 
}
?>
<?php
$fp = fopen ($fim, "w"); # w = write to the file only, create file if it does not exist, discard existing contents 
if ($fp) { 
    fwrite ($fp, $im); 
    fclose ($fp); 
    echo ("Im written"); 
} 
else { 
    echo ("Im was not written"); 
}
?>
```

Finaly Today and Im was not written, where is my error ???
i dont think that have to do with file permissions.
i forgot to write about $fwtoday = `"tips/$today/today.txt";` in the post, still not working.

Comment: Turn your errors on and tell us what it is. Why are closing and immediately opening your PHP tags?

Comment: Check the error msg, it will tell you the reason.

Comment: By seeing how you build `$fim` variable I think you are asking to be hacked.

Comment: From your code, `$fwtoday` is never defined.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Excuse me? How, exactly, is dumping the current date into a filename path "asking to be hacked"?

Comment: ah, my bad. I though I saw `$im` is used there too.

Comment: For one thing, there is no semi-colon at the end of this line `$wtoday = $today` - that alone will break your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert these lines to the front of your file, and share given errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Comment: Warning: fopen(tips/201309031413/im.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: - Check the relative path between your PHP file and the 'tips' folder!
- Check if 'tips' and $today folders are exist, otherwise make $today folder before you try to write into it!

Answer (score 2):

```
$wtoday = $today
```

Missing semicolon, parse error.

That asice, you appear to be attempting to open a filename stored in the variable `$fwtoday`, which you don't seem to have defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the definition of *$fwtoday*. Also you don't need to do this:

```
?>
<?php
```